# Despite the rotation vector sensor returns wrong readings, onAccuracyChanged never gets called

Tags: java, android, sensors

When I approach a magnet, the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor starts to return completely inaccurate values and the onAccuracyChanged method never gets called.
At the same time if I register the magnetic sensor, it detects the change in accuracy. As far as I know rotation vector is a fused sensor, which includes the magnetometer. Shouldn’t it detect the change as well?
I don’t want to register the magnetic sensor next to the rotation vector, because it delays the rotation vectors’s values, no matter how low sensor delay I set (this proves the fact that the rotation vector is indeed using the magnetometer).
Is there anything I can do to detect the accuracy correctly, or is there any other workaround?

Comment: FOr a sensor to record inaccuracy, it needs to know its readings are inaccurate.  In this case it doesn't.  Coming very close to a magnet is probably a rare enough case that it wasn't optimized for.  If you need that determination, you'll need to use the magnetic sensor as well.

Comment: ANd having the magnetic sensor on effecting the rotation sensor rate just means they're using the same thread to process data.  It doesn't mean that the rotation vector is using the magnetometer.  In fact, if anything it says the opposite-  if it was using the magnetometer then getting magnetic field readings would be nearly free.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I believe you are correct and the rotation vector use also magnetic field not just gyro  (that’s why it lose north direction when there is a magnet disruption around) but unfortunately The onAccuracyChanged never gets called.
Only TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR don’t use the magnetic field:
taken from SensorEvent class:
 TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR
* Identical to {@link android.hardware.Sensor#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR} except that it
* doesn't use the geomagnetic field.